# Does componentWillUnmount called when application crashes?

Tags: reactjs

In case that unhandled exception happens, does the componentWillUnmount function of components called?

Comment: Don't be afraid to mark this as the correct answer if it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does. Here is how you can test it in your app:

```
  componentDidMount() {
      throw new Error('error');
    }

   componentWillUnmount() {
      console.log('unmounted');
    }
```

You will see that your console messages will appear accordingly in your console